# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions / setNickname

Tags: discord.js

I got an error when trying to set the nickname of a user

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

I tested all variables with console log they're set as expected and the [prefix + "rename"] is recognize... Am I doing it wrong? ^^'

```
  bot.on("message", msg => {
        var renameID=[ChannelID]
        var userID= msg.author;
        var message = msg.content.split(' ');
        var args = message.length
        if (message[0] === prefix + "rename") {
            if (msg.channel.id === RenameID){
                if (args === 2){
                    msg.guild.member(userID).setNickname(message[1]);
                    msg.reply(" some text " + message[1]);
                }                     

            }
         }
```

edit: the bot has admin rights on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guild's role settings, your bot's role is not above the role of the user you want to edit.

Once you change that, your code should work.

Comment: Wasn't really this I tried to rename my main account which is the Owner of the serv... But works fine now after a test with another account... Thank's for your help ;)